# c++ - Building Arrays from Multiline Text Files

Tags: c++, arrays

So assume I have a file as shown below:

```
    1 2 6 2 3 7
    3 7 1 2 3 7
```

In C++, how can I store the values in two arrays like the ones below?

```
    [1, 2, 6, 2, 3, 7]
    [3, 7, 1, 2, 3, 7]
```

Comment: Don't even try. Use `std::vector`s instead of arrays. With them, it's pretty easy.

Comment: you can start with `atoi()`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868936/c-read-file-line-by-line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two `std::vector<int>`s and a `std::stringstream`:

```c++
std::vector<int> a, b;

std::string str1, str2;

if (std::getline(file, str1) && std::getline(file, str2))
{
    std::stringstream iss(str1);

    for (int n; iss >> n; )
        a.push_back(n);

    iss.clear();
    iss.str(str2);

    for (int n; iss >> n; )
        b.push_back(n);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [`boost::tokenizer`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0b1/libs/tokenizer/) and, like a comment said, use `std::vector`.